# Should the preposition 'by' be used before all the gerunds if there are more than one?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, repetition

Is this grammatically and syntactically correct?

> … by a) studying and b) helping

– or should it be:

> … a) by studying and b) by helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are equally correct, but the longer the list, the stronger the preference for the former. Also, in bulleted lists, it is good practice to always factor out as many words as possible — not only for brevity, but also for aesthetical reasons.

Comment: So your last comments dictates the use of the first case, if i understood correctly

Comment: All my comments, not just the last one, suggest the use of the first case. None of my comments, including the last one, dictate it. The last one dictates it *the least*, in point of fact, as it applies to bulleted lists, and you do not have a bulleted list here.